# HTML table not populating from mysql db

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to get a simple HTML table of the data in a table of my mysql database, but it is just showing up as a jumbled mess of the text and code in a paragraph on the page.  Any ideas what may be causing this?  Below is the code I am running:

```
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>
        Title
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="./swipe_da_code_files/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://lndapp.wpi.edu/img/favicon.ico">

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding-top: 60px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://url:Port">AdminPortal</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="default.htm">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="CreateUser.html">Create User</a></li>
                <li><a href="Database.html">Database</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Database Landing Page</h1>
</div>


<?php
  $server = mysql_connect("server", "user", "password"); 
  $db = mysql_select_db("database", $server); 
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table"); 
?>
         <table>
            <tr>
                <td>username</td>
                <td>password</td>
                <td>physicianID</td>
            </tr>

            <?php
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[username]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[password]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[physicianID]."</td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
               }
            ?>
        </table>

</body></html>
```

I have tried a variety of different ways to display the data, this was the most simple form I could think of to just display a few rows in table form, however it is not running.  I have double checked my connection details I entered, as well as the query for the database, and am certain that is not what's causing it.

[image: This is an image of the website output based on the code]

Comment: php sees this `$row[username]`. `username` as a constant. Also why are you still using `mysql_*`?? I thought you got the memo ;)

Comment: Unless configured, the file needs to `.php` seeing from the rest of the links im presuming its `.html`

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
           echo "<td>".$row[username]."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row[password]."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row[physicianID]."</td>";
```

By

```
           echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row['password']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row['physicianID']."</td>";
```

You are missing quotes!

Comment: I have added this to the code, and still unfortunately have the same issue

Comment: Is your file a `.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

Please use mysqli or PDO since mysl method is now deprecated.

```
<?php
$server=mysqli_connect("server", "user", "password" , "my_db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($server, "SELECT * FROM Table")
?>
```

then

```
<?php
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$row['password']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$row['physicianID']."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
    }
 ?>
```

Akintunde007  is correct in his/her answer that you are parsing a constant.

Comment: I have updated my code to incorporate this, both the quotes and use of non-depricated functions and have the same issue

Comment: try to execute this code var_dump($row);die; and see if you are really getting a query result. Judging by the outcome of var_dump, you can verify if your query is working or if the table column such as username, password, physicianID exist

Comment: I have added a picture of what the webpage currently prints out, if this helps at all

Comment: I didn't understand your screenshot. Is the file you are executing in .php file extension? If you execute var_dump();die; it should only show a result but on your screenshot it is showing a code. Probably PHP failed to execute

Comment: the file is in a Php extension, but for some reason is printing out all of the code, I am unsure as to what could be causing it

Comment: Please double check if your php is running. You can find tutorial in google on how to do it in Windows but on linux run service apache2 status / service httpd status

Comment: After checking it appears that my php7 is running